# How do I configure GraphQL Codegen to output a client that I can use in Node.js?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, code-generation, apollo-client

I have been using https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/ to generate TypeScript definitions, Apollo Hooks and resolvers for GraphQL for a while.

But now I would like it to generate Apollo client functions that I could use on Node.js

Node Example:

```js
const { contacts } = await queryContacts(search: 'Jack');

for (const contact of contacts) {
  // ...
}
```

How do I configure `codegen.yaml` to generate an Apollo client function, similar to `queryContacts`?

Answer (score 0):

add typescript-operation in plugins

for example:

```
overwrite: true
schema: "./apollo/schema.ts"
generates:
  lib/gen-types.ts:
    documents: ./queries/*.ts
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-apollo
    config:
      reactApolloVersion: 3
      withHooks: true
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31827198)